# Dynamic Doctrine cache namespace for each request in a Symfony application

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Doctrine cache drivers extend `Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider` which allows the cache namespace to be set.

If one configures second level cache like so:

```
second_level_cache:
    enabled: true
    log_enabled: true
    region_cache_driver:
        type: apcu
```

It will use `Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcuCache` as the cache driver.  `ApcuCache` extends `Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider`.

What's the best way to configure the Doctrine cache in Symphony so that I have access to the cache driver such that I can change the namespace dynamically?

The [configuration options](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html), eg:

```
second_level_cache:
    region_cache_driver:
        type:                 array
        host:                 ~
        port:                 ~
        instance_class:       ~
        class:                ~
        id:                   ~
        namespace:            ~
        cache_provider:       ~
    region_lock_lifetime: 60
    log_enabled:          true
    region_lifetime:      0
    enabled:              true
    factory:              ~
```

are not so thoroughly documented.

Would I create a new service and connect it via the above configuration perhaps?

How would one use `class:`, `cache_provider:`, and `instance_class:`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you really want to add a second-level cache? Or do you want to change the query-/result-cache?
Please be aware, that "Doctrine\Common" has nothing to do with "Doctrine\ORM". The latter just uses the ``Doctrine\Common\Cache`` as a library.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, if one configures the second level cache like so:

`    second_level_cache:
        enabled: true
        log_enabled: true
        region_cache_driver:
            type: apcu`

it will use `Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcuCache`.  I want to override the namespace used in the class instance.

Comment: I would just make my own cache provider like is done here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineCacheBundle/custom_providers.html also do you have a specific use for the 2nd-level cache, vs. just the regular cache?  That feature is experimental according to the Doctrine documentation and not guaranteed to be stable